# Upgrade php from 5.4 to 5.6 on Centos 6 without causing an outage

Tags: php, linux, centos

I'm currently running CentsOS 6.6 and php 5.4 (from REMI repo) on my vps. I want to upgrade my php framework to the newest version, but it requires php 5.6.

Since I have a few dozen users using my webapp, is there a way for me to upgrade php from 5.4 to 5.6 without causing an outage?

I'm new to Linux and I've never done a php upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to keep 2 copies of the website, one with `php5.4` and one with `php5.6`.

And let the users work until you are ready with the new version, then switch the symbolic link / directory mapping / dns to the new site.

To give a more specific answer, I'll need to know your server (`apache`/`nginx`) and your setting (shared hosting/dedicated).

### Edit:

[Running multiple php versions on the same server](https://web.archive.org/web/20130707085630/http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server)
This link describes the configuration needed on CentOS, running Apache.

Comment: I pay for a small vps hosting, and i'm using apache. I can't install the newest framework since it requires php 5.6. Do you suggest I pay for a second vps hosting and install php 5.6 there?

Comment: Add a `<Directory>` tag in `httpd.conf` with a new website, on the same server, and configure that directory to run different `php` version

Answer (score 0):

Software Collections are designed to allow parallel installation.

See documentation on: https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/

SCL of PHP 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0 are available in above site, in **remi** repository, and soon in **centos-scl** repository.

Notice, as a single mod_php version can be used, you, as explained in the referenced link, have to used php-fpm.